# How to convert int[] to short[]?

Tags: c#, arrays, type-conversion

```
int[] iBuf = new int[2];
iBuf[0] = 1;
iBuf[1] = 2;

short[] sBuf = new short[2];
Buffer.BlockCopy(iBuf, 0, sBuf, 0, 2);

result  
iBuf[0] = 1  
sBuf[0] = 1  
iBuf[1] = 2  
sBuf[1] = 0  

My desired result  
iBuf[0] = 1  
sBuf[0] = 1  
iBuf[1] = 2  
sBuf[1] = 2
```

The result is different from what I want.
Is there a way to convert without using loops?

Comment: The simple answer is no - int uses 4 bytes, shorts use 2 bytes - so essentially you need to copy alternate pairs of bytes. The answers given below will work - but under the covers of the methods they will be using loops. Depending on size of you arrays, it may be possible to write quicker solutions with a method of your own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Array.ConvertAll method.

Example:

```
int[]   iBuf = new int[2];
  ...
short[] sBuf = Array.ConvertAll(iBuf, input => (short) input);
```

This method takes an input array and a converter and the result will be your desired array.

Edit:
An even shorter version would be to use the existing Convert.ToInt16 method. inside ConvertAll:

```
int[] iBuf = new int[5];
short[] sBuf = Array.ConvertAll(iBuf, Convert.ToInt16);
```

So, how does ConvertAll work? Let's have a look at the implementation:

```
public static TOutput[] ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>(TInput[] array, Converter<TInput, TOutput> converter)
{
    if (array == null)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.array);
    }

    if (converter == null)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.converter);
    }

    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<TOutput[]>() != null);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<TOutput[]>().Length == array.Length);
    Contract.EndContractBlock();


    TOutput[] newArray = new TOutput[array.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        newArray[i] = converter(array[i]);
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

To answer the actual question... no, at some point there will be a loop involved to convert all values. You can either program it yourself or use already built methods.

Answer (score 0):

int is 32bit long and short is 16 bit long, so that way of copying data won't work right.

Universal way would be to create a method to convert ints to shorts:

```
public IEnumerable<short> IntToShort(IEnumerable<int> iBuf)
{
    foreach (var i in iBuf)
    {
        yield return (short)i;
    }
}
```

and then use it:

```
int[] iBuf = new int[2];
iBuf[0] = 1;
iBuf[1] = 2;

short[] sBuf = IntToShort(iBuf).ToArray();
```

Comment: why would creating additional method be the easiest way when I can be done with one line?

Comment: Is there any reason for OP to write a method when .NET already provides this functionality - see answer from Milster.

Comment: Yea but if he is using .NET 2.0 or older, can he use LINQ methods then?